# PyGTK moving two windows at once

Tags: python, windows, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am using Python 2.7 with PyGTK and GTK of the according versions. (>>> import gtk >>> gtk.pygtk_version (2, 24, 0) >>> gtk.gtk_version (2, 24, 8)) I am writing an application where there is a main window and optionally (according to the state of a toggle button) also a settings window next to it.

I am trying to move the two windows at once (make the settings window STICK to the main window, move it with the main window). It works by default on my friends MacBook (no effort on my part), but not on my Windows 7 machine. I found a workaround that makes the settings window jump to the main one AFTER the move of the main window is finished - that is however not what I am aiming for.

Edit: FYI, the "settings_window" has the parent "main_window" which is (i guess?) doing the right job for Mac OS.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.
Thx, Erthy

Comment: If you don't want the settings window to move separately from the main window, why don't you just put the settings in the main window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this example works (on Ubuntu):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding:utf8   
""" 
This PyGtk example shows two windows, the master and his dog. 
After master window moves or changes size, the dog window moves to always stay at its right border. 
This example should also account for variable thickness of the window border.
Public domain, Filip Dominec, 2012
"""

import sys, gtk

class Main: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.window1 = gtk.Window(); self.window1.set_title("Master")
        self.window2 = gtk.Window(); self.window2.set_title("Dog")

        self.window1.connect('configure_event', self.on_window1_configure_event) # move master -> move dog
        self.window1.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit()) # close master -> end program

        self.window1.show_all()
        self.window2.show_all()

    def on_window1_configure_event(self, *args):
        print "Window 1 moved!"
        x, y   = self.window1.get_position()
        sx, sy = self.window1.get_size()
        tx = self.window1.get_style().xthickness
        self.window2.move(x+sx+2*tx,y)

MainInstance = Main()       
gtk.main()
```

Comment: Works on windows 7 too, successfully implemented. Let's see what it does on mac. Thank you sir! :)